# Unable to find Full Text search in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition 3 months ago. Now that I want full text search capability I downloaded the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition with advanced services from 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=25174

When I am installing I am not able to see the option for full text search. I clicked on add features to an existing instance of SQL Server and I see only database engine services, management tool basic and SQL client connectivity SDK.
I am not able to find the option for full text search.

Am I missing anything?

I ran the following query

```
 use master
 go
 SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

and it gave me 0

Comment: You may need to uninstall and reinstall:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34655/installing-full-text-search-on-sql-server-2008-r2-express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to uninstall and install it again. This solved the problem